# How does this non-type template parameter expansion work? + Possible bug in gcc?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

```
template <typename T, typename T::tag...>
void f() {}

struct Tagged { using tag = struct{}; };
struct Untagged {};

void test() {
    f<Tagged>();
    f<Untagged>(); // fails
}
```

This code compiles on gcc 8.1, whereas clang 6.0 and MSVC 19 fail. Note that `--std=c++14` is passed to all three.

Clang's Error:

> :9:5: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
>
> ```
> f<Untagged>();
>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> :2:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure
>   [with T = Untagged]: no type named 'tag' in 'Untagged'
>
> void f() {}
>
> ```
>  ^
> ```

MSVC's error:

> (9): error C2672: 'f': no matching overloaded function found
>
> (9): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'void
>   f(void)'
>
> (9): note: With the following template arguments:
>
> (9): note: 'T=Untagged'
>
> (9): note: '__formal={default_valueAttribute}'

However, if we comment the offending part:

```
template <typename T, typename T::tag...>
void f() {}

struct Tagged { using tag = struct{}; };
struct Untagged {};

void test() {
    f<Tagged>();
    //f<Untagged>();
}
```

it works on all three. 
Now there are actually two questions:

1) Is it a bug in gcc that the first snippet gets accepted?

2) Why does the expansion with `struct` in place of tag work? As per C++ reference, non-type parameter must be either

- `std::nullptr_t` (since C++11);
- integral type;
- lvalue reference type (to object or to function);
- pointer type (to object or to function);
- pointer to member type (to member object or to member function);
- enumeration type.

Comment: Please specify which version of the standard you are compiling for and which version you are interested in.

Comment: You should include the error in your question.

Comment: Because `typename` here is used to disambiguate a `tag`, which is a dependent type

Comment: There are no non-type template parameters in this code.

Comment: @geza Of course it's a type. But the OP's point in that part is that when `T=Tagged`, the type `typename T::tag` is not a valid type for a template parameter.

Comment: gcc 7 doesn't accept the `Untagged` version.

Comment: *"As per C++ reference, non-type parameter must be either"*: as anonymous `struct{}` is not is the list, wonder why `f<Tagged>()` compiles...

Comment: @xskxzr I'm wondering how do you think the linked "duplicate" question answers second part of _my_ question?